# Active Admin Rename the resource in different places

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

The [documentation](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#rename_the_resource) allows you to rename a page pretty easily, but not exactly in the way I'd like.

Given this code: `ActiveAdmin.register User, :as => "Static"` gives a menu name of `statics`

I was wondering if there was a way to customize it so the name in the menu is not pluralized => `static`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rename the menu item([source](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#rename-the-resource#labels)):

```ruby
menu label: 'Static'
```

---

Rename title in the top left corner([source](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/features/show/page_title.feature)):

```ruby
index title: 'Static'
```